# Lorentz Transformations and length contraction when reference frames moves towards each other

Tags: special-relativity

I'm just starting to learn special relativity, so I'm sorry if my question is not clear or not make any sense.

I'm studying the subject with a textbook, and in the textbook they describe the development of the Lorentz Transformations equations and the implications: length contraction and time dilation.

The development of the equations starts with the assumption that the  two reference frames are consolidated at t=t'=0, and from that moment, one of the reference frames starts moving with speed v on the x axis, while the other reference frame is at rest.
And then they describe the implications of that equations which is length contraction and time dilation.

This scenario as what I understand is a scenario where the two reference frames are moving away from each other.

My question is,
if the reference frames were moving towards each other, would the Lorentz Transformation equations be the same?
Would there still be a time dilation and length contraction?
Or maybe there will be a time contraction and length dilation?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Your question is without sense. In any case the frames are moving away from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Both reference frames cover an unbounded space of three dimensions. They completely overlap in their coverage. In 'standard configuration', $x$ and $x'$ axes lie along the same line. The $y$ and $y'$ axes coincide at $t=t'=0$, as do the $z$ and $z'$ axes.

As time goes on the S' system moves in the $x$ direction as judged from the S system. The origins of the S' and S' system are moving away from each other; it couldn't be otherwise because they were closest together at $t=t'=0$. But that doesn't mean that the systems themselves are moving away from each other: they continue to overlap in their coverage of space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I realized that my question isn't clear. I meant, what if at t=t'=0, the systems were not closest together (i.e x not equal to x') and when time goes on, the x and x' are getting close to each other

Comment: But even if the origins of the co-ordinates get closer together (until they pass each other and start to get further apart) this has little significance because the systems overlap in their coverage of space. There will still be time dilation and length contraction.